# Запуск команды из cmd через pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Для запуска сервера django нужно в cmd написать

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Возможно ли это сделать из pycharm? не обязательно эту команду, любую? например, чтобы делать это нажимая на кнопку через Tkinter?

Comment: Так PyCharm может запускать питоновский скрипт и передавать аргументы ему. В этом вопрос? Ещё есть встроенный терминал, в котором вы можете ввести эту команду. А вообще там для django есть специальная конфигурация Django Server

Comment: а какую команду нужно выполнить, чтобы запустить 'manage.py runserver' в pycharm?

Comment: from myfirst import manage
manage.runserver() так, например, не получается

Comment: Как вы запускаете скрипты? Зелёной кнопкой? Так вот действия этой кнопки зависят от конфигурации, добавьте нужный аргумент в ней

Comment: С PyCharm не работал, но она основана на  IntelliJ IDEA, так что должно быть похоже. Рядом кнопкой запуска есть ComboBox (с именем вашего проекта или вашей конфигурации запуска). Нажимаете на него -> Edit configuration -> Progarm arguments -> пишете туда runserver. Для PyCharm, возможно будут отличия

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать в терминале, скриншот ниже.

[image: Терминал PyCharm]

Только нужно иметь в виду, что **полноценная поддержка** Django только в PyCharm Professional.

Comment: В PyCharm Community нет конфигурации Django Server?

Comment: @dIm0n yes......

Answer (score 1):

В панели инструментов сверху жмете на `Add configuration` (если настроек запуска еще не было) или на комбобокс слева от зеленой стрелки (если уже есть какая-то конфигурация), выбираете `Edit configurations`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее слева сверху жмете кнопку `+`, добавляете конфигурацию Python:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В поле `Script path` указываете путь к скрипту manage.py, в поле `Parameters` пишите `runserver`, потом жмете "Ok":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого стартуете сервер зеленым треугольником/стрелкой, в консоли внизу жмете на ссылку рядом с `Starting development server at...` - сайт откроется в браузере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Готово.

Для других программ (не django) в настройках конфигурации достаточно указать путь к запускаемому скрипту (`runserver` - это специфика django).