# Как сделать так, чтобы не приходилось каждый раз писать слово python в начале строки в терминале Pycharm?

Tags: django, pycharm

Купил новый ноутбук.
На старом ноуте я писал все команды в терминале без слова "python", например:

...myproject> manage.py runserver

На новом ноуте установил PyCharm, приходится добавлять 'python' вот так:

...myproject> python manage.py runserver

иначе команда не срабатывает.
Где что настроить, чтобы не писать каждый раз python ? Вообще хочется понять, от чего это зависит?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно все дело в том, что при установке python’а ты не поставил галочку «ADD TO PATH»

Comment: Возможно, но я потом вручную добавил в переменную path путь до python.exe - и не помогло.

Comment: Попробуй переустановить python. Должно помочь.

Comment: @ТимофейДемидов зачем его переустанавливать ради добавления в `PATH`?!

Answer (score 0):

В общем, команда manage.py открывала файл, вместо того, чтобы запускать скрипт, потому что в Windows ассоциация файлов .py стояла с Pycharm. После того, как я связал этот тип файла с python.exe проблема решилась.

Comment: Проще в PyCharm команду запуска настроить, чтобы при нажатии зеленой стрелки manage.py запускался: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1160695/1365 Тогда и вводить ничего руками не нужно будет, и ассоциации не будут влиять.